# Is this considered within bounds of "be nice" policy? If so, why?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging, be-nice-policy

Quoting a comment (emphasis mine):

> There is no such thing as a "bad" question. There is a such thing as nitpicking critics that parse questions and answers to **satisfy their own peer-pressure or ego driven psychosis**.

Is this considered within bounds of "be nice" policy? If so, why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is not. When you see a similar comment, please flag it as "rude or abusive".

I took a look at the recently declined "rude or abusive" flags and found the comment quoted here under [a *question*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31797/what-is-the-narrowest-possible-definition-of-war) which got flagged as such. The flag was likely declined because the moderator who handled the flag read *the question* and found nothing rude or abusive about it (I can't find anything rude or abusive about it either).

I subsequently deleted the comment, another comment from the same author which was also insulting the community in general and two comments which replied to it.

When you find a comment rude or abusive, please **flag the comment** and not the question or answer it was posted under. That way we know what specifically you are complaining about.

Comment: I was under impression that I DID flag the comment, apparently somehow I clicked flag on a post. *headdesk*. Thanks for fixing!

Answer (score 5):

That's probably my fault.

I agree that It violates the be-nice policy.  When handling comment flags, you're given 2 buttons, and they're both negative d-words:  "decline" and "delete".  I clicked on the wrong one.

I had realized after the fact, I clicked on the wrong one, but at the time, I had this notion that this was a user who wasn't familiar with the purpose of the site, so I decided to respond to his comment instead.

Again, I'm sorry.  It was totally my fault.  If I could go back and do it differently, I would.

As a note, comment flags are kinda lumped in with the flags on the question, and other moderation-related notes, so I can understand how it could have looked to Philipp like a flag on the question.

Comment: no need for apologies, I just wanted to make sure I had grounds to re-flag same comment, with Meta link as proof assuming the Meta consensus agreed with me. Also, the link in my flag history doesn't have #xxxxx suffix, so I was convinced by earlier answer that it may have been a question flag.